# Movie recorded on phone reports inconsistent number of frames when imported to blender (Blender 2.8 vs 2.9)

Tags: video-sequence-editor

When I import same movie clip, recorded with my phone, in Blender 2.80 it automatically recognize 1278 frames with FPS 42.28 and that's correct, but blender 2.81 and above recognizes only 923. So when I render clip to frames I'm missing 355 frames although in sequencer when I slide through timeline, I can preview those frames.
I tried to play with FPS and Base settings but with no luck.

Does anyone know what's happening here?

Thank You

[image: Blender 2.80]

[image: Blender 2.90]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185251/render-is-duplicating-random-frames-when-loaded-into-3d-tracker/185253#185253 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53510/vse-problem-blurring-license-plate-mask-is-jumping-all-over-video/53514#53514

Comment: Read the following link: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162362/is-it-required-converting-videos-to-an-image-sequence-before-doing-motion-tracki/162364#162364

Answer (score 1):

42.28 is a non standard frame rate.

Phone cameras use every trick in the book to create small files by using **variable frame rate** and long GOP **inter-frame** compression, where the information for each frame depends on the information of a reference key frame.

Video encoded with such schemes cannot be imported into blender without problems.

The easiest way to deal with this is to use an external program to **transcode** the file into a single stable frame-rate with **intraframe** encoding (where all of the information for every frame is contained within the current frame).
Blender will work fine with those.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. I'll try to fixate frame rate on my phone. Still, it's strange that older versions of Blender do it right. Cheers

Comment: Okay, stop @susu. How do you know all these things? :)

Comment: @JachymMichal OK I will stop...