# Video editing, source from same camera with wrong FPS. Some 120fps some 30fps

Tags: import, video-sequence-editor, video

I made a videos (using my honor view 20). All with the same settings on the phone (30FPS), just different shots.

Then when I add them inside the video editor, some videos are said to be 120fps while others are said to be 30FPS.
Now if they were all imported as 120fps that would not be a problem. But because some are randomly 30fps and some 120fps, after importing a first one which is recognized as 30fps, then when I import one recognized as 120fps it has 4 times more video than audio.

I tried to use speed control to fix that, by increasing video speed but the exported video is very poor, it's stuttering on those sped up 120fps parts.

I doubled checked on VLC each videos and confirm they are all 30fps. So there's some bug which makes Blender recognizing some videos as 120fps.

Is that well known? Is there a work around?
Thanks

Comment: Related: [Video recorded on phone has inconsistent number of frames](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/195339/78972)

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have Variable Frame Rate? May be VLC gives you the average framerate? You can check it with Media Info app (https://mediaarea.net/en/MediaInfo) and eventually recode the 'offending' video to Fixed Framerate with Handbrake (https://handbrake.fr/).

Comment: Yes it is well known. Video from a phone or screen cast will almost never work on blender, unless it is converted to a stable frame rate.