# Video faster than audio after rendering?

Tags: rendering, animation, video

So I'm trying to edit this funny video from 2 years ago... And when I render the video the video is a lot faster than normal but the audio is normal. Also everything seems fine in preview.. I have audio sync, audio shredding and frame dropping on and the frame rate is correct. So any ideas what might cause this?

EDIT: Ok it seems to have something to do with the beginning of the video because if I render a random part of the video that doesn't include the beginning it will be fine but if I start the rendering from the beginning it will all be messed up... Any ideas on
 how to fix this?

Thanks in advance,
~Jere

Comment: That kind of thing can happen if the video you're editing was shot with one frame rate (say 30 fps) but you're rendering at a different setting (like 24 fps.)

Comment: @PatrickMarchand Yeah that's what I ment by "frame rate is correct".. So the video is shot in 50 fps and I'm rendering at 50 fps

Comment: Can you include your .blend, video, and audio?

Comment: @ShadyPuck Do you mean the whole project? If so no... I don't want to show peoples' faces sorry.

Comment: Welcome to BSE @Jere , please don't include the answer in the question, you can answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: @Georges I didn't answer the question... The problem is still unsolved

Comment: OK, I got the impression that it's solved, when you said it's only when you skip the beginning, may be other people will get the same impression and skip the question, can you edit it in a way to show that you're still expecting an answer?

Comment: @Georges ok i put a question in the end of the edit even though a bit late :/ kinda rage quitted blender for a while... It's just so hard to use.

Comment: Try exporting the footage to an Image Sequence first (maybe with an external tool) and then import that if that helps. Guess, the internally used ffmpeg codec just has problems with the [proper decoding](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49219/2843).

Answer (score 2):

You are not in playing back at real speed. Go in the *Timeline Window > Playback* menu, and enable *Frame Dropping* option. It will respect the real speed but at the price of some frame droppings.