# Video gets cut in half after adding it to the VSE in 2.77 or 2.77a but not 2.76b?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I add a video to the VSE by adding it or dropping it with all the correct frame rate and length but it gets cut in half in 2.77 and 2.77a. Added the same video without making sure the frame or length was correct in 2.67b and the whole video was there. Is there something new you have to do with 2.77 or 2.77a to add a video to VSE? This happens on a Mac and Windows using 1080 or 4k .mp4 video.

Comment: There's a new feature since 2.77 to adapt the frame rate when importing the first clip. You can uncheck it using the *Add clip* function, searching for your clip in the file browser, it's on the left side at the bottom. See if this helps.

Comment: No this does not help. Please add a film clip to your VSE anyway you want and see what happens. I have tried adding with and without the box checked for frame rate. I Have added and dropped the clip on the VSE and have tried several different clips all come out the same they get cut to around half.

Comment: Did you set your Frame Range to more than the default 250?

Comment: As said above frame range and frame rate set correctly and also tried without setting correct frame range and frame rate. The audio comes in full just not the video. When I add it its 1953 frames even if the frame range is set to 1, 250 or 4000 and it should be 3912.

Comment: Well, never had this problem that way and I used all these versions. Only had the issue with the AVCHD FullHD video clips being twice as long which was due to [interlaced footage](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49219/2843), but half as long has never been a problem for me. So you might provide some more information - Screenshots or your blend file.

Comment: Samoth You are awesome for trying to help me and not giving up so quickly!! This is strange this does not happen to you. Here is a link to the video (Test Video.mp4) and the .blend file (test video.blend) with the video packed into the file. 
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/yoy7dhj9bsxt5xv/AABHa1uLMFChs-BOYY4VCqk2a?dl=0

The video was shot with a LG G3 phone. VLC player says the frame rate is 29.451966 codec is H264 MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (avc1).

Comment: I have given this over to the Blender.org developers as a bug and they are working on it. I will come back when they have solved this problem I am having and update.