# Video with unusual frame rate will skip or repeat a frame

Tags: video

In Blender, I overlaid a video onto the camera using background image to help make an animation (my objective is to copy the video). Unfortunately it has a very unusual frame rate. I have matched the animation's frame rate with the video's but sometimes the video would skip a frame and repeat a frame. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Please use a more specific title on the question, preferably one that reflects the issue you are having...

Comment: The issue could be the video being in a delivery format (mts or mpg4 or something similar) in which the video is encoded using I, B, and P frames, which means that the information of a particular frame is not complete in every frame but is reconstructed using information from some preceding and subsequent frames. Or it might be that is compressed using some kind of variable framerate (not supported in blender). Convert the video to an image sequence and use that instead.

Comment: @cegaton I reinterpreted the videos unusual frame rate to a more common value and it is now normal. I think changing the animation frame rate does nothing.

Comment: I use a [Workaround](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49219/2843)...