# Fast repeats/flashes video clip

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

So I've been pulling the last bit of my few hairs out of my skull for half a day now trying to figure out why my rendered video is NOT smooth like it is in the preview. 
Demo: http://seodagger.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/1111-2222.avi 
It's like it loops each soft cut (in the video strip) a dozen times before it moves on. This does not happen when I play it in the editor, but happens every single time I render it. Any ideas?
Been following a bunch of "rendering tutorials" just to make sure I am not missing anything but I'm starting to go nuts :(

Comment: Should be a workaround: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49219/2843

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codecs.

Prefaced with my usual “very difficult to diagnose from a distance.”

All codecs are *not* created equal, and are complex beasts when it comes to decoding. This is *especially* true for encoded files that could be subject to massive frame compression such as screen captures.

Best test is to render each source file long sequence into a  stills or AVI JPG format from within Blender prior to editing, and then edit the resultant output.

If this works, and if you are so inclined to learn about the dark alchemy of codecs, I could explain further if required.

Comment: Hmmm... ok. I get what you're saying. Does that mean I lose the 7 hours worth of editing I put into it? Ouch :( 

For the record, this is my first time using Blender so the learning experience alone would have been worth it, but still. My head hurts just thinking about redoing it all, lol

Comment: Assuming your media is soft linked to the same file, possibly not. Just replace that soft link on the strip with your new AVI JPG and you might be fine.

Answer (score 0):

> Best test is to render each source file long sequence into a stills or
>   AVI JPG format from within Blender prior to editing, and then edit the
>   resultant output.

Boom. That worked. Followed your advice and it worked like a charm. I sure am glad I did not have to redo it from scratch. Thanks a bunch **troy_s**!

Comment: Alright alright... I said it worked, and it is now watchable, but it is still doing it a LITTLE bit. I tried rendering the 16 minute video in 3 parts in hops it might fix it completely but it does not appear to fix it. Anything I might do wrong with the codec this time?

Comment: I would suggest that a still image format *should* fix it, but that may be a challenge to conform to an existing edit that used a single file codec. AVI RAW should be full frames for every frame. If it still jumps at a cut, it is likely there are still P / B frames in the source, and *not* non-GoP. Hard to know at this point. Other thing to try is to generate timecode (not LTC) indices within Blender to hopefully sort out those few remaining pinch points.