# multiple frame rate movies causing problems

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I have a large number of video strips that are 120f/s and some that are 30f/s that I want to merge together in a scene.

The method I have been using, up until now, is to import all the movie strips. Then set the frame rate for the project to 30f/s and on the 120f/s strips, add a speed control effect strip, to change the speed to that of the audio.

1) For some reason this method doesn't work for the 120f/s, could someone explain why?

2) is there a way to have 120f/s and 30f/s movie strips side by side without converting one frame rate to the other before bringing them into Blender?

Comment: I'd do it with a [workaround](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/49219/2843) only importing the same frame rate into Blender and doing the rate adjustments outside... But else Mikeycal Meyers explains how to [fiddle around](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NrX1sK_ZQqs&index=27&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4) with these Speed Strips for [that purpose](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Rdraa7YzcE&list=PLjyuVPBuorqIZOWRDICIZ2WCFapHHYLPv&index=16).

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your suggested workaround. Could you please suggest a simple, free, windows 10 compatible, way of changing the framerate.

Comment: Use [Handbreak](https://handbrake.fr/) to convert it before importing...